# correlation between basis vectors

Tags: correlation, interpretation, matlab

how come Matlab give me the result corr(u,v)=-1
u=[1 0]' and v=[0 1]'  (i.e., two orthogonal column vectors, basis of the Euclidean plane ...)

Suddenly this makes no sense to me ... their scalar product = 0 ... they should be perfectly UNcorrelated?

i know it works out to -1 with the correlation formula $dot((x-mean(x)),(y-mean(y))/(norm(x)*norm(y))$ but could someone enlighten me ? (it's very frustrating ... i seem to miss something (and I have been working with such things for a while...)

To summarize: why (logical understanding point of view) are they negatively perfectly correlated (-1) whereas I would expect them to be perfectly UNCORRELATED (0) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two data points: `(u[0], v[0])` and `(u[1], v[1])`. In terms of $x$ and $y$ axis, when $x=0$ then $y=1$. When $x=1$, $y$ went down and became $y=0$. So when $x$ increases, $y$ decreases. I wouldn't interpret the data points as vectors. Even if you were to interpret them as vectors, clearly the two vectors are orthogonal so there is perfect anti-correlation. No correlation means if $x$ is increasing $y$ stays the same

Comment: oh thanks yes of course it makes perfectly sense ... i wonder why I made this terrible confusion... any idea why?

Comment: Well it can be hard to see the relation when there are only two data points

Comment: yes that's true but what about orthogonality? How would you define "relation" or whatever we can call it, between correlation and orthogonal vectors such as U and V here

Comment: also the fact that there is a dot product in the definition of CORRELATION is misleading because as they are orthogonal...

Comment: Note that your two data points are not $u$ and $v$. $u$ contains all Xs and $v$ contains all Ys. Your data points are $(u[0], v[0])$ and $(u[1], v[1])$(which happen to be the same as $u$ and $v$). Nevertheless, you need to first subtract the mean from each direction and then visualize the vectors. You get something like $(0.5, -0.5)$ and $(-0.5, 0.5)$ which you can see they point in different directions. I will update my answer to add an intuitive explanation

Comment: also i just thought that as we can interpret the correlation of the centered vectors as the cosine of the angle between these centered vectors, then arccos(-1) = 180 degrees which 2as far as they can be"in a sense because 360 degrees = 0 = colinear and same sign

Comment: yes i think i understand what you mean, (0.5, -0.5) and (-0.5, 0.5 ) are the centered vectors which are at 180 degrees resulting in a dot prod of -0.5, this time and not 90 degrees. what do you think of my previous thought?

Comment: Yes you have the correct intuition. The angle of the centered vectors does indeed capture the notion of correlation since it also ignores the length of each vector(which is the reason why we also normalize)

Comment: hum interesting thanks. yet what to say about ortogonality ?

Comment: Orthogonality was basically an accident here. $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ would give you the same result and they are not orthogonal. That's why I prefer to not interpret the data points as vectors. But if you prefer vectors then you can try and visualize the difference vector. You can see that both in my example and yours, it's the same.

Comment: ok we can clear it but if possible i would very much like to speak to you in private (if you want)? i can quickly drop and remove an e-mail addr (i m doing a PhD im computer science )

Comment: oh ok found it. I will contact you at your email there then